# How to configure person to be notified if any check-in policy was avoided in TFS?

Tags: tfs, checkin-policy

We are  using TFS 2008 and switched on "Work Items" check-in policy (requirement to assosiate check-in with 1 or more work items).

In this case developers still have an option to avoid following policy: they could mark “Override policy failure and continue checkin” check box and do commit without associating check-in to any work item.

AFAIK, email should be send to TL/TFS administrator about this.

How can I manage email recipients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure the email for check-in policy override, you have to install the [Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en), It will add the Alerts Explorer option to Team Menu in Visual Studio Client.

Go to Team -->Alert Explorer, Click on New Alert-->Check in Alerts-->Check-In to specific folder with policy override-->Click OK.

[image]

It will show the Alert Definition tab which will have a send to option where you can add the required email recipients.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, it should be done by each person who is interested in by configuring own alerts for case when 'PolicyOverrideComment' is not empty.